Declaring strong pointer to forward declared type
#include <binder/IBinder.h>
#include <binder/IServiceManager.h>
#include <utils/String16.h>

using ::android::sp;
using ::android::String16;
using ::android::IBinder;
using ::android::IServiceManager;
using LocalRegistrationCallback = IServiceManager::LocalRegistrationCallback;

namespace android {
    class GonkNativeWindow;
}

class CobaltServiceCallBack : public virtual LocalRegistrationCallback {
    public:
        void onServiceRegistration(const String16& name, const sp<IBinder>& binder) override;
        void init();
        virtual ~CobaltServiceCallBack() {};
        bool IsCobaltRunning() { return mIsCobaltRunning;}
    private:
        sp<IServiceManager> mServiceManager;
        bool mIsCobaltRunning = false;
        sp<android::GonkNativeWindow> mNativeWindow;
};

In the above code i have decalred forward declared type "GonkNativeWindow" and trying to declare strong pointer to that type. But am getting complier error as below:
android/out/target/product/am30ah/obj/objdir-gecko/b2g-sysroot/include/utils/StrongPointer.h:305:14: error: member access into incomplete type 'android::GonkNativeWindow'
9:18.80         m_ptr->decStrong(this);
What is wrong with the code here?

GonkNativeWindow is incomplete at the point sp<android::GonkNativeWindow> and sp needs a template parameter that needs to be a complete type.

This isn't related to pointer. The error clearly says you're using an incomplete type.

The problem is that you defined the destructor in a header file. As a result, the compiler tries to synthesize this destructor for every translation unit where this header file was included.
And every destructor must not only execute its body, but also call the destructor for each field of a class. So there is an attempt to use the destructor of sp<android::GonkNativeWindow> and this tries to use the destructor of GonkNativeWindow which is incomplete in one of the sources.
To fix this: just declare the destructor ~CobaltServiceCallBack in the header and define it in the respective cpp file. Note that this source file must include the respective header file so the class GonkNativeWindow is complete and the destructor can be fully synthesized.
The problem may reappear for other implicitly created member functions (like copy/move assignments/constructors) depending on the context and the solution is the same.
offtopic:
those using .... in global scope of header file is a bad practice! This have negative impact on on anyone who will include this header file and some unexpected name conflicts can pop up.

@user1237538 If the answer solves your problem you could click '✔' to mark it as an accepted answer.You can also upvote any helpful answer (accepting and voting is separate). See here: What should I do when someone answers my question?.
